# In this Rails app view loop, how can I include CSS button styling?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, haml

I want the "complete" below to have a fake button styling, basically a border and a colored interior.

What would be the best way to do this? I tried to suffix class: 'btn btn-mini' but that doesn't work (for obvious reasons, as it's not really a button).

```
- @tasks.each do |task|
  %tr
    %td= task.content
    - if @dayhash[task.day_id] == "today"
      - if task.start != nil && task.stop.nil?
        %td underway
      - elsif task.start !=nil and task.stop !=nil
        %td complete
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  - elsif task.start !=nil and task.stop !=nil
    %td
      .btn.btn-mini Complete
```